# Paypal Buttons on Site Not Working, Do I need Sandbox to sell?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, dreamweaver

I am using Dreamweaver 8 to code. No issues uploading to server (ipower), but my paypal "BUY NOW" and "ADD TO CART" buttons are not working, and redirect user to screen that says "Things are not working at the moment" and invite user to "Return to Merchant".

Do I have to use Sandbox or something? Never had this issue before. I do not want to use Shopify if I can copy and paste button code. Whats up?

Also, is there another "Paypal" like service I can use where I just copy code, paste code, get paid without having to integrate sandbox or anything extra?

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox is for testing integrations. You do not need to use the sandbox if your integration works.

Buttons created via https://www.paypal.com/buttons will in general simply work. If they are not working for you, it is likely because Dreamweaver is changing the code supplied by PayPal. For example, inserting extra table or form tags.

Search for a tutorial on how to insert 'raw HTML' or a 'widget' or 'snippet' in your version of Dreamweaver, so that it does not change the HTML generated by PayPal.